# Using flash to notify user of previous registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use my Users controller to notify the user when their email has already been used in a registration, but even when the email already exists, I still get the error "Plase validate your input and try again," rather than "You've already registered! Thanks for being enthusiastic!" Is using the controller not the create way of achieving this behavior?

In the rails console (assuming "foo@bar.com" is in the database"), when I use `user = User.new(name:"Example", email:"foo@bar.com")` then `User.find_by_email(user.email)` it does return the proper User entry, so I'm not sure if I'm on the right track and just executing it incorrectly or what. Any ideas?

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Thanks for supporting cofind! We'll be in touch!"
      redirect_to root_path
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    else
      if @user.email == User.find_by_email(@user.email)
        flash[:error] = "You've already registered! Thanks for being enthusiastic!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:error] = "Plase validate your input and try again."
        redirect_to signup_path
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
if @user.email == User.find_by_email(@user.email)
```

checks the user's email (a string) against a user record (an `ActiveRecord` object) which will always be false.  You should change that to

```
if User.where(email: @user.email).exists?
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have known it would be something so simple!